# Error: Expected 'var' keyword in property declaration

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm getting the following error: `Expected 'var' keyword in property declaration` in my `enum` re-assignment:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // Return Screen based on State
    var screen = Screen.login
    screen = .editProfile // Expected 'var' keyword in property declaration
    var body: some View {
        if screen == .home {
            return AnyView(HomeView())
        }
        else if screen == .editProfile {
            return AnyView(LoginView())
        }
        else {
            return AnyView(LoginView())
        }
    }
}

enum Screen {
    case login, home, editProfile
}
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: What do you mean by `screen = .editProfile`?

Comment: `screen = .editProfile` is out of any context - what do you suppose to achieve with it?

Comment: Give enumeration types singular rather than plural names, so that they read as self-evident:

`var directionToHead = CompassPoint.west`
The type of directionToHead is inferred when it’s initialized with one of the possible values of CompassPoint. Once directionToHead is declared as a CompassPoint, you can set it to a different CompassPoint value using a shorter dot syntax:

`directionToHead = .east` (source:https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)

Comment: I'm simply changing the value of `screen` @Asperi

Comment: _When_ do you want to change it?

Comment: I'm learning about enums (new to IOS) so I'm just testing changing the value here @Sweeper

Comment: Well, if you just put that line there, neither Swift, nor me, is going to know when you want that line to be run...

Comment: Ok then, I want it to run in the `if` statement (when `screen == .editProfile`) however it still gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put instruction out of any execution block inside type declaration, so here is a possible examples

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // Return Screen based on State
    var screen = Screen.login       // << initialisation !!

    var body: some View {
        if screen == .home {
            return AnyView(HomeView()
                     .onTapGesture {self.screen = .editProfile}) // << one !!
        }
        else if screen == .editProfile {
            return AnyView(LoginView())
        }
        else {
            return AnyView(LoginView()
                     .onAppear {self.screen = .editProfile})    // << two !!
        }
    }
}
```